# Find the coordinates of the centroid

Tags: calculus

I'm having a problem setting this problem up and solving it for the $X$ and $Y$;

Set up the integrals (but do not evaluate them) to find the coordinates of the centroid of region A ( The curve is $y=\sin(e^x-1)$ shown on the interval $0 \leq x \leq 1$)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2PsG.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Comment: What is the region $A$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I read your statement correctly, here's the region $A$:

[image]

Its area is $$A = \int\limits_{x=0}^1 f(x)\ dx$$

and center of mass has coordinates:

$$\bar{x} = \frac{\int\limits_{x=0}^1 x f(x)\ dx}{A}$$

and

$$\bar{y} = \frac{\int\limits_{y=0}^{f(1)} y (1 - f^{-1}(y))\ dy}{A}$$

and $f^{-1}(y) = 1+ \ln (\pi - \sin^{-1} y)$